# Converting decimal numbers to binary / hex / octal notation

Tags: java, numbers, hex

Is there any package in Java which has methods to convert the entered decimal number to binary,hex and octal. Also for converting vice versa for all other conversions.

Comment: why do you want a direct API , you can write a simple method for that

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you look for answers? What didn't work as intended and why?

Comment: you should have searched it before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can try using the [java.lang.Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class, where you will find methods like:

- [toBinaryString(int i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29)
- [toHexString(int i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29)
- [toOctalString(int i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toOctalString%28int%29)

For the reverse operation (converting from octal, hex and binary to decimal), you can use the [Integer#parseInt(String input, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method. For example, if you want to convert an octal string to decimal, here's what you need to do:

```
String octal = "some-octal-number-as-a-string";
int result= Integer.parseInt(octal,8);
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** That is available in Java class(e.g `Integer`, `BigInteger`) not in java package.